# Open a setup python file?

Tags: python, ply

I recently downloaded the VSL compiler developed by Matthieu Amiguet (http://www.matthieuamiguet.ch/pages/compilateurs) to learn how to compile with Python PLY. In the README it says to type python setup install. I readapted the code to work in python 3. Here is what I got as an error:

[image]

Here is setup.py

```
import sys, os, shutil

def install():
    print ('Installing...')
    if not os.path.exists(vsldir): os.mkdir(vsldir)
    pyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir('VDK/src/') if not os.path.isdir(f) and f.endswith('.py')]
    for p in pyfiles:
        shutil.copy('VDK/src/'+p,vsldir)
    shutil.copy('VDK/bin/vslc',INSTALLDIR)
    shutil.copy('VRE/vsl',INSTALLDIR)
    shutil.copy('VRE/vsl',INSTALLDIR)
    shutil.copy('vmake/vmake',INSTALLDIR)
    os.chmod(INSTALLDIR+'vslc',111)
    os.chmod(INSTALLDIR+'vsl',111)
    os.chmod(INSTALLDIR+'vmake',111)
    print ('Installed!')

def uninstall():
    print ('Desinstalling...')
    if os.path.exists(vsldir): os.system('rm -R '+vsldir)
    if os.path.exists(INSTALLDIR+'vslc'): os.system('rm '+INSTALLDIR+'vslc')
    if os.path.exists(INSTALLDIR+'vsl'): os.system('rm '+INSTALLDIR+'vsl')
    if os.path.exists(INSTALLDIR+'vsl'): os.system('rm '+INSTALLDIR+'vmake')
    print ('Desinstalled!')

def printHelp():
    print ('''usage : python setup.py COMMANDE
            - install : installation of the compiler and runtime environement
            - uninstall : uninstall the compiler et the runtime environement
                (this two last command need root password)''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pythonpath = [path for path in sys.path if path.find('python')!=-1 and path.find('site-packages')!=-1]
    print ('========================================'.center(80))
    print ('=====         VSL Compiler         ====='.center(80))
    print ('===== David Jacod , Anthony Mougin ====='.center(80))
    print ('========================================'.center(80))
    if len(pythonpath)==0:
        print (' * No python path found. Installation failed')
        sys.exit(-1)

    if os.name=='posix': INSTALLDIR = '/usr/local/bin/'
    elif os.name=='nt': INSTALLDIR = 'c:/VSLCompiler/'

    pythonpath=pythonpath[0]
    vsldir = pythonpath+'/vslcomp/'
    if len(sys.argv)<=2:
        if sys.argv[1]=='install': install()
        elif sys.argv[1]=='uninstall': uninstall()
        else: printHelp()
    else:
        printHelp()
```

Comment: This looks like a very custom setup.py file, which is unusual for python. This file is trying to find path to at least one USER_SITE location such that the path contains the words `python` and `site-packages`. On Mac/Linux, a typical USER_SITE location may look like `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`. I'm not sure what this would look like on Windows.

Comment: I agree. Do you have any idea on how I  can modify it correctly?

Comment: There is probably no good solution. You could comment out the `if len(pythonpath)==0` section and then define `pythonpath` to be whatever the USER_SITE location is for your system. But, I anticipate more problems down the road.